# Firebase Cloud Firestore or Realtime database in terms of pricing for my chat app?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I have been developing an app which has a feature to chat with other users. I have been been really confused for the past few days trying to find out which would be the better database to use in terms of pricing, I am talking about going at scale here.

Whenever a user sends a message he creates a document and while doing so I am also checking if the other user is online or not, for which I read another document. On average I have to make around 7-8 writes per message and 8-10 reads per message. Also whenever a user opens a conversation he sees the last 15 messages, and if he scrolls then he sees more. This increases the reads as well.

Also I want to know if I send a message and the other user gets it , who previously read 15 documents to see the last 15 messages , when I send a new message , the 15th message gets replaced with the new one , so do I get charged for the 15 document reads again?

Pricing is the main concern here, please help me find the best approach here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase has a [database recommender](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rtdb-vs-firestore) and a [pricing calculator](https://firebase.google.com/pricing#blaze-calculator) in its documentation to help you answer this question. I'd expect it to point to the Realtime Database here, primarily based on the fact that you'll have many smaller write operations.

For your second question (please limit yourself to a single question per post going forward): if your listener remains active, or if your local cache already contains the 14 unmodified documents, you will be charged only one document read (for the new document that needs to be read on the server to return it to the client).

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. Really appreciate it :)